# what is meaning of if html == 0 and html == 2 jquery ajax php

Tags: jquery, ajax

what is meaning of  if html == 0  and html == 2 jquery ajax php

```
if(html == 0)
{
    $("#loginmsg").html('Invalid email Id or Passwords or usertype');
}
else if(html == 2)
{
    $("#loginmsg").html('Invalid email ');
}
else
{
    window.location.href="index.php"
}
```

Comment: It is probably bad naming of a response variable from a request.

Comment: It is not PHP. `==` means equality checking operator. `(if html == 0)` means they are checking whether `html` is equal to `0`.

Comment: That's a response from the server.... `html==0` is comparison  if server response is zero do this

Comment: `undefined == 0` and `undefined == 2`

Comment: can you paste your whole ajax here?

Comment: what is meaning of 0 and 2 here ????????

Comment: can you send me link i want read this document or live example